# Sitecore Cortex Processing Engine Error

Tags: cortex

I've been trying to implement the Sitecore Cortex Demo (https://github.com/adeneys/cortex-processing-demo).
I've added the model and followed the steps as listed on the repo but on the 3rd step, Registering Tasks, the last two tasks are failing and I'm getting the following error in Processing Engine logs

```
    2019-06-26 19:41:47.743 +05:30 [Error] Error Executing worker. Task Id: 8d6646ab-4bcd-4c29-97c0-2e071d3a1af8.
Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Exceptions.DeferredTaskExecutorException: Error Executing Deferred Task Executor. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[ProcessingEngineDemo.Common.SpotifyMusicRecommenderOptions]' while attempting to activate 'ProcessingEngineDemo.Common.SpotifyMusicRecommender'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.TaskServicesFactory.CreateInstance[TCast](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String typeName, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 options)
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.DeferredTaskExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.DeferredTaskExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.BaseExecutor`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Diagnostics.TaskExecutorCountersDecorator.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Agents.TaskAgent.<RecurringExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to restart the processing windows services?

Comment: Is the DLL for the class ProcessingEngineDemo.Common.SpotifyMusicRecommenderOptions deployed?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I am having the same issue.